# Need help in customizing mobile responsive search bar (stretching to max width according to the screen size)

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I'm currently using a plugin called ubermenu on wordpress. It is a plugin to help customize menu bar. Everything work well and had it make to optimize my theme. However, I found out that when I open the website via mobile, everything went well except for the search bar which is not stretched to fit the mobile screen. Other parts of the menu are stretched. What CSS code should I inject in to make it fit the screen?

[image: Here is the attached screenshot of what it look in mobile.]

The code for the search bar is "menu-item-20642"

```
menu-item-20642 {
   width: 800px;
   max-width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: share code here!!!

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: sorry. updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've fixed it!

here is the code! hope it helps for those who are using ubermenu!

```
.ubermenu .ubermenu-search .ubermenu-searchform{
    width:95%;
}
```

insert this under css tweak mobile. and you're done ;)